# Can google access data on compute engine virtual machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud-compute

I'm using an always-free VM on Google Cloud (e2-micro). When creating the instance, there's an option `Enable Confidential Computing service`, but that requires `n2d` machine, not part of the always-free resources.

Does that mean Google can read my VM's data?

In other words, without that option enabled, what can Google read on my VM?

I'm not worried about system health monitoring data. I'm only concerned with files and folders that I put there.

Answer (score 1):

Google has written policies that describe what they can access and when. Google also provides the ability to log their access.

Confidential Computing is a different type of technology that is not related to Google accessing your data.

Start with this page which provides additional links:

[Creating trust through transparency](https://cloud.google.com/files/gcp-trust-whitepaper.pdf)

This Whitepaper is a good read. Page 9 answers your question:

[Trusting your data with Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/files/gcp-trust-whitepaper.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You may have heard of Encryption in Transit, or Encryption at Rest.  Confidential Computing just encrypts data while it's being processed within the VM as well (Encryption during Processing?).

You need to use n2d machine types because it uses tech/features available on the AMD EPYC procs.

Comment: Yes I have heard of those terms. But I don't understand what they mean exactly. What can Google read and what can they not?

Comment: Encryption in Transit is when data is sent from one machine to another.  The network traffic is encrypted -- this is to prevent someone from intercepting your network traffic and being able to read stuff (i.e. passwords).   Hence sites like StackOverflow have SSL/TLS certs.

Encryption at Rest is when the data is at the destination and is saved to disk or some sort of storage.  This way, if someone were to break into Google's datacenters and steal their servers, they're unable to read the data without the decryption key.

Comment: Confidential computing protects the data while it's being processed -- from unauthorized access (i.e. other processes or bad actors)

Comment: I guess neither of those comments really answers your question about whether Google can access your data.  Technically they can, but only if they have reason to (i.e. you have a support ticket and they need to get access to your systems -- but there are separate access logs that will log their actions for those types of situations).

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

A Confidential Virtual Machine (Confidential VM) is a type of N2D Compute Engine VM running on hosts based on the second generation of AMD Epyc processors, code-named "Rome." Using AMD Secure Encrypted Virtualization (SEV), Confidential VM features built-in optimization of both performance and security for enterprise-class high memory workloads, as well as inline memory encryption that doesn't introduce significant performance penalty to those workloads.
You can select the Confidential VM service when creating a new VM using the Google Cloud Console, the Compute Engine API, or the gcloud command-line tool.

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/confidential-computing).

You can check their privacy document [here](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/6056650#zippy=).